# Parsing Turtle from Freebase RDF API in Javascript

Tags: rdf, freebase

I'm looking for a neat way to parse RDF from the [freebase RDF API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/rdf-overview). I tried the `jquery.rdf.js`/`jquery.rdf.turtle.js`, but it seems to have trouble dealing with the dot notation CURIEs. For example, below is the Turtle I get from Freebase about the city `"Oslo"`:

```
@prefix key: <http://rdf.freebase.com/key/>.
@prefix ns: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>.
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>.
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.

ns:m.05l64
  ns:base.aareas.schema.administrative_area.administrative_area_type    ns:m.0hzcklw;
  ns:base.aareas.schema.administrative_area.administrative_parent    ns:m.05b4w;
  ns:base.biblioness.bibs_location.country    ns:m.05b4w;
  ns:base.biblioness.bibs_loca
```

Causing the error:

```
uncaught exception: Invalid Turtle: Expecting ':', found '.05l64
    ns:base.a...'
```

Is there a way to replace the `.`, or a different library or workaround?

Answer (score 5):

I think your basic problem is that the Freebase RDF appears to be using the latest version of the [Turtle specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) which is currently a W3C Candidate Recommendation.  This version of the Turtle spec does allow for QNames that use `.` in them (plus lots of other previously illegal characters) whereas the older and technically unofficial [Turtle specification](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/turtle/) that most current tools implement did not.

The current specification is from Jan 2013 and the earliest reference I can find to more liberal Prefixed Name syntax that allows `.` is in the July 2012 draft.  Conversely the tool you are using was last updated in 2009 according to its SVN so it isn't a surprise that it doesn't support this syntax.

I did find one [blog post](http://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2013/04/30/lightning-fast-rdf-in-javascript/) that talks about developing a Turtle parser to the latest spec in Javascript that may do the trick.

Comment: you should check Antonio Garrote's rdfstore-js (https://github.com/antoniogarrote/rdfstore-js) library which is probably the most recent js lib to write rdf stuff in javascript